# Animating between Composables in Navigation with Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have started trying out Navigation for compose.

I created my 2 Composables and everything is working fine.

But what I'm missing is Animations (or Transitions) between the pages. I didn't find any resources pointing out how to do it in Compose.

I know all animations are based on states in Compose, but the only thing I know is the Navigation Back Stack.

Comment: There seems to be a new `NavOptionsBuilder` arg in `navigate` method. But it's `anim {}` lambda doesn't apply the animation (compose-nav: alpha09)

Comment: Give [Navigator Compose](https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/navigator/tree/master/navigator-compose) a try it supports animations as well.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the composable I made to show enter animation (configure preferable effects in "enter" and "exit" parameters)

```
@Composable
fun EnterAnimation(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visibleState = MutableTransitionState(
            initialState = false
        ).apply { targetState = true },
        modifier = Modifier,
        enter = slideInVertically(
            initialOffsetY = { -40 }
        ) + expandVertically(
            expandFrom = Alignment.Top
        ) + fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.3f),
        exit = slideOutVertically() + shrinkVertically() + fadeOut(),
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "dest1"
) {
    composable("dest1") {
        EnterAnimation {
            FirstScreen(navController)
        }
    }
    composable("dest2") {
        EnterAnimation {
            SecondScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `'AnimatedVisibility(Boolean, Modifier = ..., EnterTransition, ExitTransition, Boolean, () -> Unit): Unit' is deprecated. AnimatedVisibility no longer accepts initiallyVisible as a parameter, please use AnimatedVisibility(MutableTransitionState, Modifier, ...) API instead`

Answer (score 12):

`Accompanist` version `0.16.1` and above supports animation between destinations. Here is the [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animations-in-navigation-compose-36d48870776b) for more info.

```
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.16.1")
```

---

```
import com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHost
import com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.composable
import com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.rememberAnimatedNavController


val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()

AnimatedNavHost(navController, startDestination = "first") {
    composable(
        route = "first",
        enterTransition = { _, _ -> slideInHorizontally(animationSpec = tween(500)) },
        exitTransition = { _, _ -> slideOutHorizontally(animationSpec = tween(500)) }
    ) {
       FirstScreen()
    }
    composable(
        route = "second",
        enterTransition = { _, _ -> slideInHorizontally(initialOffsetX = { it / 2 }, animationSpec = tween(500)) },
        exitTransition = { _, _ -> slideOutHorizontally(targetOffsetX = { it / 2 }, animationSpec = tween(500)) }
    ) {
       SecondScreen()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The problem with Accompanist's AnimatedNavHost is that you cannot cast it to TestNavigationProvider. Which makes the AnimatedNavHost untestable in isolation. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/testing/TestNavHostController

Comment: from now on this is supported by the official navigation library https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.7.0-alpha01

Answer (score 6):

In alpha-09 this is not supported. :(

Please, star this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172112072

Comment: this has finally been incorporated https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.7.0-alpha01

Answer (score 5):

Due to [yesterday's update](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha05) (version `2.4.0-alpha05`):

*Navigation Compose’s NavHost now always uses Crossfades when navigating through destinations.*

Comment: Great. Thanks for this. Did you find out how to add your own?

Comment: @mmm111mmm I used the solution delivered by Константин Семочкин for a custom animation

Answer (score 2):

Lately Google Accompanist has added a library which provides Compose Animation support for Jetpack Navigation Compose.. Do check it out.

https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/navigation-animation

Answer (score 1):

From now on all the functionality in the accompanist library has been portet to the official compose `NavHost` navigation library. See the [following](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.7.0-alpha01). hence there is no longer a need to use accompanist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library I did. It provides easy navigation and is written using AnimatedVisibility so you can use compose transitions to animate any screen state (enter, exit)
https://github.com/vldi01/AndroidComposeRouting