# AnimatedVisibility deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When attempting to declare code to animate between two different composables, a 'deprecated' error is returned. How can this be fixed and cleared?

> `AnimatedVisibility(Boolean, Modifier = ..., EnterTransition, ExitTransition, Boolean, () -> Unit): Unit' is deprecated. AnimatedVisibility no longer accepts initiallyVisible as a parameter, please use AnimatedVisibility(MutableTransitionState, Modifier, ...) API instead`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                navController = rememberNavController()
                MyNavGraph(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun EnterAnimation(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = true,
            enter = slideInVertically(
                initialOffsetY = { -30 }
            ) + expandVertically(
                expandFrom = Alignment.Top
            ) + fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.3f),
            exit = slideOutVertically() + shrinkVertically() + fadeOut(),
            content = content,
            initiallyVisible = false
        )
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyNavGraph(
        navController: NavHostController
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screen.Shoes.route
        ) {
            composable(route = Screen.Shoes.route){
                ShoesScreen()
            }

            composable(route = Screen.Brands.route){
                BrandsScreen()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ShoesScreen() {...}

    @Composable
    fun BrandsScreen() {...}
}
```

Comment: If you are using the Navigation Component, you shouldn't be using `AnimatedVisibility` at all to animate between composable screen. Have you read the [blog post about customizing animations between composable destinations](https://link.medium.com/4d4oPnDfdwb)?

Comment: Yes but what about the first answer in [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643015/animating-between-composables-in-navigation-with-compose) Should this be avoided too?

Answer (score 0):

That particular function is deprecated. You can use the new api which use [MutableTransitionState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/MutableTransitionState) instead of plain boolean.

```
import androidx.compose.animation.core.MutableTransitionState

@Composable
    fun EnterAnimation(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {

 val initialVisible = true
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visibleState = remember { MutableTransitionState(initialVisible) },
        enter = slideInVertically(

        ) + expandVertically(

        ) + fadeIn(),

    ) {
    content()
    }
  }
```

You can also do like this by adding `AnimatedVisibilityScope` to the composable type,

```
    fun EnterAnimation(content: @Composable AnimatedVisibilityScope.() -> Unit) {

 val initialVisible = true
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visibleState = remember { MutableTransitionState(initialVisible) },
        enter = slideInVertically(

        ) + expandVertically(

        ) + fadeIn(),

    content = content)
  }
```

Comment: `Parameter 'content' is never used` so what would need to go in "//Compose content"? Would it be the name of the composable?

Comment: Updated. In your case it should be `content()`

Comment: Weirdly, this is not working for me as it just shows a static change without animation